# My motorcycle didn't start yesterday but now it does, why and should I do something about it?

Tags: motorcycle, starting, yamaha

Two days ago my Yamaha FZ25 motorcycle didn't start (it doesn't have a kick starter, only electric starter), I called the dealer's mechanic who after checking if the battery was ok and who knows what else, told me he didn't know what the problem was, he didn't fix anything. He was able to start it by pushing it.

After that it started ok every time I tried: When I came home after the incident, also started ok yesterday (I rode it an hour) and also started ok when I came home, I've just tried to start it today and it starts ok.

What could be the cause for it not starting that single time? Should I be worried? Did that happened to you? Should I take it to the mechanic again?

Notice I bought my motorcycle new, it now has a mileage of 930 miles (1500km). Thanks!

Comment: was it raining?

Comment: It could have just been that the battery terminals had loosened up during the first 1k miles, but the mechanic would have noticed that. I wouldn't worry about it, unless it starts happening again.

Comment: @SolarMike: no, it wasn't raining, nor cold, it was at night but the nights are not too cold here

Comment: @Sam: Thank you, I hope it doesn't happen again... did it happen to you yet?

Comment: @Roberto not every bike fails to start once at 930 miles...

Comment: It has happened to me before with a different bike. I stopped to get gas after riding for an hour. 5 minutes later, the bike wouldn't start. After scratching my head for 15 minutes feeling like an idiot, I tightened the battery cables and the bike started right up. "Live and learn"!

Comment: @Sam & SolarMike if you put your answers as answers (instead of comments) I'd be able to upvote them...

Comment: did it even turn over?